# Retrieving properties of a function $p(\cdot)$ given that $\text{ess} \sup p(x) < \infty$ or $\text{ess} \inf p(x) = \infty.$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure, supremum-and-infimum

I believe the title of the post is almost self explanatory but either way I would like to elaborate a little more on the topic.

Let us fix a Lebesgue-measurable function $p\colon \Omega \to [1,\infty]$. The question I am studying is quite simple and can be stated as follows:

> What conclusions can we retrieve about $p(\cdot)$ if we know that $p_+
>  = \text{ess} \sup_{x \in \Omega} p(x) < \infty$ or $p_- = \text{ess} \inf_{x \in \Omega} p(x) = \infty? $

Here, when I say "conclusions", I am mainly interested in boundedness properties of the function $p(\cdot)$ and it is also important to say that I am studying each one of the possibilities $p_+ < \infty$ or $p_- = \infty,$ individually.

**My thoughts.**   I dealt with the case $p_+ < \infty$ quite easily. I was able to prove that

$$ p_+ < \infty \implies p(\cdot) \text{ is essentially bounded.} $$

If someone whises, I could post further details on this implication.

Now, on the other hand, I am having quite some trouble with the case $p_- = \infty.$ Any hint to proceed developing this case would be kindly appreciatted.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: If $p_{-}=\infty$ then for every $n$ we have $\mu\{x\,:\,f(x)<n\}=0.$ Hence $$\mu\{x\,:\, f(x)<\infty\}\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu\{x\,:\,f(x)<n\}=0$$ Thus $f(x)=\infty$ almost everywere.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc thanks for your comment. I can't follow why $p_- = \infty$ implies that for every $n$ we have $\mu \left\{ x  \, \colon \, f(x) < n \right\}. = 0$ Can you elaborate a bit on this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $$p_{-}=\sup\{a\,:\,\mu\{x\,:\, p(x)<a\}=0$$ If $p_{-}=\infty$ then for every $a$ there holds $\mu\{x\,:\, p(x)<a\}=0.$ We have $$\{x\,:\, p(x)<\infty\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{x\,:\, p(x)<n\}\\ = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{x\,:\, n-1\le p(x)<n\}$$ Thus $$\mu \{x\,:\, p(x)<\infty\}\\ = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu\{x\,:\, n-1\le p(x)<n\}\\ \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu\{x\,:\, p(x)<n\}=0$$ Therefore $p(x)=\infty$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Sorry for the delay Richard. I was only now able to go through your answer properly. There is something I don't understand quite well. Why does $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu\{x \colon p(x)  < n\} = 0 \, \, ? $$ I understand that for every $n \in \Bbb R$ the equality $\mu \{x \, \colon p(x) < n \} = 0$ must hold, but we also have infinity in the sum, can you elaborate a little bit more in this equality? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have re-edited. Hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again. Unfortunately, I don't think your edit answers my doubt: what exactly is the argument behind the equality below ? $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu\{x \, \colon \, p(x) < n \} = 0. $$

Comment: Do you agree that $\mu\{x\,:\,p(x)<n\}=0$ for any $n$ ?

Comment: Yes, that part I understood. I also understood the equality $$ \{ x \, \colon \, p(x) < \infty \}  = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{ x \, \colon \, p(x) < n \}.$$ I also understood that this leads to the inequality $$ \mu \{ x \, \colon \, p(x) < \infty \} \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu\{ x \, \colon \, p(x) < n \}.$$ I just don't understand how this last (infinite) sum can equal $0$. What happens when $n=\infty$ ? (I think that for every $n \neq \infty$, the measure is $0$ and so all we are left with is the case $n=\infty$).

Comment: The summation does not include $n=\infty.$ It is just the sum of a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ which is defined as the limit of partial sums i.e.  $\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^Na_n.$